# A Faster Bubble Sort Variant Using Binary Approach

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, bucket-sort

I've been doing some interview question preparation and in the process came up with a little variant on Bubble Sort that incorporates what I've learned about binary search into the inner loop for swapping. So the time complexity sees roughly a 50% reduction over O(n^2). I guess my question is am I wasting my time with Bubble sort? Should I just learn Bucket Sort and be done with it?

I've been testing with the following input.

```
int[] nums = { 9878, 1, 4, 8, 5, 7, 88, 1, 54, 2, 2, 9878, 5, 7, 3, 11, 1, 4, 8, 5, 7, 88, 1, 54, 2, 2, 5, 7, 3, 11 };

public static int[] sortWBinary(int[] ar)
{
      var swapped = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length && swapped; i++)
      {
          swapped = false;
          for (int k = i, j = ar.Length - 1; k < ar.Length - i - 1 && j > 0; k++, j--)
          {
              if (ar[k] > ar[k + 1])
              {
                  var temp = ar[k];
                  ar[k] = ar[k + 1];
                  ar[k + 1] = temp;
                  swapped = true;
              }

              if (ar[j - 1] > ar[j])
              {
                  var temp = ar[j - 1];
                  ar[j - 1] = ar[j];
                  ar[j] = temp;
                  swapped = true;
              }

          }
      }

      return ar;
  }
```

**VS.**

```
public static int[] sortWoBinary(int[] ar)
{
    var swapped = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length && swapped; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < ar.Length - i - 1; k++)
        {
            if (ar[k] > ar[k + 1])
            {
                var temp = ar[k];
                ar[k] = ar[k + 1];
                ar[k + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return ar;
}
```

Comment: Imo what’s a waste of time is learning the “best” sort method. If you’re using C#, the only sort method you need is `source.Sort()`. Knowledge of .NET APIs, popular frameworks, and CICD is going to take you a lot further it that world. To be clear, what I mean is that the mere fact you have altered an existing sort algorithm and are now looking for input on how to improve it indicates to me you have problem solving skills and a sense of teamwork. That’s more valuable than an intricate knowledge of sorting algorithms.

Comment: Why do you say that the first aproach is 50% faster. The complexity is the same for both of them (except you want to execute first approach in paralell)

Comment: I took the delta between the two regarding their respective number of iterations and divided that by the number of iterations the original executes. It works out to right around 50% change. Which makes sense because we're potentially doing double the swapps per iteration and the inner loop's lower bound increments with every iteration of the outer. So for the inner not quite log(n), but closer.

Comment: @cSkillzMartin there is no BEST SORTING ALGORITHM. Each has its uses and its selection depends on dataset properties, size, memory available etc ... using bubble sort is OK in some cases in others is not ... the same goes for quick sort, merge sort, bucket sort and all the others ... Bubble sort can be faster than quick sort even bucket sort in some cases and in others it cant ...

Answer (score -1):

For sort, know the difference between `O(n log(n))` and `O(n^2)` and know that you always want to use the former if you have enough data to care about what you are doing.

Here are all the types of sort that you should ever need to be able to talk about.  If I am interviewing you, I only care that you know the first two.  I might ask you to implement the third after telling you how to write it, but I wouldn't care whether you know it.

1. Whatever is in your library.  Any programmer who doesn't know to reach for that first is a danger to their codebase and shouldn't be hired for that reason.
2. External sort tools such as the Unix `sort` utility or the `ORDER BY` function in SQL.  When you need to toss data around and have the choice, do not suck it into your memory to sort it, get it sorted somewhere more efficient first.
3. Merge sort.  (For experts.)  Exactly twice in my life I have needed to write a sort and the first two options did not suffice.  Both times it was the same story.  Too much data to use a library routine, and not a fit for external tools for a complicated set of reasons.  So it had to be an external sort (ie intermediate file kept out of memory on disk).  If you need to write an external sort, merge sort is your friend.
4. Quicksort.  (When interviewed by wannabe experts.)  Occasionally someone will ask you how the library sort actually works.  I would say, "There are a lot of ways that it can work, but for a long time quicksort was the standard.  Do you want me to show how that works?"  That is usually the answer that they want.  It is rare to find someone who knows that quicksort has largely been replaced by timsort.  Someone who does can dig further and get told, "During this century, platforms have been moving towards timsort.  It was invented for Python, and has been adopted by Java, Chrome and other platforms.  I would have to look up how it works."
5. Radix sort.  (When interviewed by smartasses.)  If someone asks you whether you can sort faster than `O(n log(n))` you will need to know about this one.  Knowing the answer will likely cause them to work harder to show that their nerd credentials are better than yours.  This would be a mark against my wanting to work with them.